# Aligning text to the right of matrices in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I wonder how I could make LaTeX align to the right some specific descriptions I wrote about the operations I apply to matrices. For example, here is a screenshot of what I have right now but I want it done better:

[image]

The code I used was:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{systeme, mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix} 
&= 2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{propositie 4.3.7 (toegepast op onderste rij)} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{propositie 4.3.5 ($R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3$)} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{propositie 4.3.8 ($R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1$)} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 0 & -5 & -10 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{($R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - 4R_1$)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I want the descriptions right aligned, prefered with first the statement 'proposition', and underneath in brackets the operation which I applied, and all of this next to the corresponding matrix (to the right). How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually looking for in the output. By your description it seems that the last row is what you are looking to replicate for all the rows? Can you be more precise on how you want the output look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't abuse `\tag`; there's no need for the explanation to be flush with the right margin; also, the explanations should be left aligned with each other.

Since it's impossible to accommodate those explanations in one line, I use a `tabular` for splitting them across two lines.

Don't forget loading `fontenc` with the `T1` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <---- don't forget
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{systeme, mathtools}
\usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newcommand{\explain}[1]{&&\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
&= 2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
  \explain{propositie 4.3.7 \\ (toegepast op onderste rij)} \\
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
  \explain{propositie 4.3.5 \\ ($R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3$)} \\
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
  \explain{propositie 4.3.8 \\ ($R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1$)} \\
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 0 & -5 & -10 \end{pmatrix}
  \explain{($R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - 4R_1$)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you insist to abuse `\tag*`, just change the definition of `\explain` into

```
\newcommand{\explain}[1]{\tag*{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}%systeme, 
%\usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
    \begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
\det\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    & = 2 \det\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
        &&  \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
        propositie 4.3.7\\ 
        (toegepast op onderste rij)
        \end{tabular}                       \\
    & = -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
        &&  \text{propositie 4.3.5 ($R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3$)}     \\ 
    &= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
        && \text{propositie 4.3.8 ($R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1$)}   \\ 
    &= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 0 & -5 & -10 \end{pmatrix}
        && \text{($R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - 4R_1$)}
 \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

Normally macro `\tag` is used for tagging equation, not for their description. Instead them I use `\text` and `tabular` environment.

Comment: would be nicer if the 2-line description were left-aligned with the 1-liners.  (i'm not sure why the `tabular` is being indented.)

Comment: @Barbara Beenton, now I see that I forgot to eliminate `tabcolsep` ... It should be `\begin{tabular}{@{}l}`. I will correct my answer. Thank you for tip.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tabular` environments in the argument of `\tag*` to split the explanations into two parts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 2 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix} 
&= \phantom{-}2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}propositie 4.3.7 \\
          (toegepast op onderste rij)\end{tabular}} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & -2 & 5 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}propositie 4.3.5\\
          ($R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3$)\end{tabular}} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}propositie 4.3.8 \\
          ($R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - 3R_1$)\end{tabular}} \\ 
&= -2 \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -8 & -4 \\ 0 & -5 & -10 \end{pmatrix} 
  \tag*{($R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - 4R_1$)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```